# How do I use the form hook alt to edit fields of inline entity form?

Tags: commerce, forms, entities

I am trying to use the hook_form_alter to modify the fields of an Inline entity form in a commerce product display node.

I know how to edit a normal field but this does not work for an entity form field. How do I go about editing a field, for example changing the price field label?

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 8):

As per IEF's [API docs](http://drupalcode.org/project/inline_entity_form.git/blob/45b85198925702138a70755a500201a26f2aa0fb:/inline_entity_form.api.phphttp://drupalcode.org/project/inline_entity_form.git/blob/45b85198925702138a70755a500201a26f2aa0fb:/inline_entity_form.api.php), you've got:

- hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()

  > Perform alterations before an entity form is included in the IEF widget.
- hook_inline_entity_form_reference_form_alter()

  > Perform alterations before the reference form is included in the IEF widget.
  >
  > The reference form is used to add existing entities through an autocomplete field
- hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter()

  > Alter the fields used to represent an entity in the IEF table.
  >
  > The fields can be either Field API fields or properties defined through hook_entity_property_info().

I think the first would be most appropriate here, probably something like (guessing at the array keys here, they might be different):

```
function MYMODULE_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {
  if ($entity_form['#entity_type'] == 'commerce_product') {
    $entity_form['commerce_price']['#title'] = t('New title.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Clive, thanks for this great answer!  It helped me a lot. Can you also explain how can I work with the submit handler of IEF?  because $entity_form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] is not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!